# Why can't closed subsets of polymorphic variants type check against the superset?

Tags: ocaml

A variant `` [`A | `B] `` is not type compatible with a superset like `` [`A | `B | `C] ``

I understand they cannot be unified unless an `>` is added to the subset or a `<` to the superset, but I am curious about whether there is an example where accepting this kind of typing could lead to incorrect programs.

In a very simplistic use like this:

```ml
let return_a : bool -> [ `A ] = fun _ -> `A

let foo : bool -> [ `A | `B ] = return_a
```

It seems perfectly safe to accept the implementation, as the declared type of `foo` is a strict superset of the implementation type (which is the type of `return_a`). However (as expected) it will not type check:

```
Error: This expression has type bool -> [ `A ]
but an expression was expected of type bool -> [ `A | `B ]
The first variant type does not allow tag(s) `B
```

It actually looks to me as a more restrictive type than

```ml
let return_a : bool -> [ `A ] = fun _ -> `A

let foo : bool -> [< `A | `B ] = return_a
```

Which does type check.

Is this restriction on the usage of polymorphic variants just a limitation of how type inference works or is there a practical reason to mark the first snippet as ill-typed?

Answer (score 4):

The type `` [`A | `B] `` is a subtype of `` [`A | `B | `C] ``. OCaml supports subtyping, but it has to be explicit.

```
# type abc = [`A | `B | `C];;
type abc = [ `A | `B | `C ]
# type ab = [`A | `B];;
type ab = [ `A | `B ]
# let f (x: abc) = 14;;
val f : abc -> int = <fun>
# let (x: ab) = `A;;
val x : ab = `A
# f x;;
Error: This expression has type ab but an expression was expected of type abc      
       The first variant type does not allow tag(s) `C
# f (x :> abc);;
- : int = 14
#
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question was more whether that restriction prevents actual errors or is more an artefact of the algorithms used by ocaml to unify types.